# What is the most efficient way in Spark to get unique pairs in a PairRDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Given an `initial: PairRDD[(Long, Long)]`, what is the most efficient method to get an `other: PairRDD[(Long, Long)]` which contains each pair of `initial` exactly once? (i.e. filters out duplicate pairs.)

Specifically, is there something more efficient than `initial.distinct()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case, when you make no assumptions about data distribution and you require exact results `distinct` implements pretty much a minimal correct solution which:

- drops duplicates for each initial partition
- shuffles the data
- drop duplicates for each shuffle output

So unless you want to modify internals there is not much you can improve here.

That being said if you can make some assumptions and / or reduce requirements you can improve on that.

- If you expect rare duplicates you can avoid map side combine to reduce memory usage and GC in the initial phase. You can do it for example with `combineByKey` with `mapSideCombine` combine set to `false`.
- If you can accept some loss of data you can use a set of bloom filters at the cost of additional job.
- If data is orderable you could try to use external sort followed by a linear scan to avoid storing hash map in memory. For starters you can take a look at the `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` and `ExternalSorter`.
- If RDD has partitioner set (for example is a result of some kind of `byKey` operation) you can perform only local distinct-like operation with exact choice depending on amount of data.

Comment: doesn't a PairRDD hold the pairs with the same key in the same partition?

Comment: No it doesn't unless it has been explicitly or implicitly (join, sort, some kind of by key operation) partitioned and it means going back to square one - shuffle.

Comment: Interesting. A couple of follow-up questions: what do you mean by external sort? and how do you avoid map side combine?

Comment: I updated the answer. For the first part you can start with `combineByKey`. Regarding external sort there are a few mechanisms in Spark including [`ExternalSorter`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4f369176b750c980682a6be468cefa8627769c72/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/ExternalSorter.scala#L90) and some "unsafe" options. It is rather unlikely you'll need to access any of these directly and `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` should be enough.